# HighPart Piechart overlapping

Tags: highcharts

I want to make highchart like this. as of now I am able to add radius but it is over riding the first one.
I am able to make this one.
http://jsfiddle.net/amritmishra/eqnhLw5s/14/
[image]`borderRadius to use`

this is the URL which I was able to achive.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what particularly do you want to implement and what the problem is? What can I suggest is add some margin: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fyuwnscj/

Comment: actually, if you see in this image attached. the colors section one side is below and the other part is above.
like yellow is above violet,

but the jsfiddle. Yellow is below from both sides.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation. I am afraid that it is impossible to achieve from regular Highcharts API options... A lot of core changes are required to render it this way. The only workaround which came to my mind is to render a circle in the place where this ronded point path should be. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7tcjxLa5/ or without animation: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jko2qmr9/ let me know what do you think about this workaround and if you want to implement it. If yes I will help you to make this circle responsive.